# convert ISO8601 String to reformatted date string(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iso8601, dateformatter

I'm pulling a date from a JSON database. The Date is formatted like 2017-06-16T13:38:34.601767 (ISO8601 I think). I'm trying to use the ISO8601DateFormatter to format the date from 2017-06-16T13:38:34.601767 to 2017-06-16. So far I can't even get the pulled string to format as a date.

```
let pulledDate = self.pulledRequest.date
var dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: pulledDate)
print(date!) //nil
```

I'm not sure if I've got the date format wrong and it's not ISO8601 or if I'm not using the ISO8601DateFormatter as intended.

1.) Is it an ISO8601 Date?
2.) Am I using the ISO8601DateFormatter correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you have 6 digits in your milliseconds block (.601767) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. That's been throwing me too. I saw someone else somewhere (I know, that's helpful lol) say they had the same thing and it was ISO8601

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO8601 has several different options, including a timezone. It appears that by default the `ISO8601DateFormatter` expects a timezone indicator in the string. You can disable this behaviour by using custom options like so:

```
let pulledDate = "2017-06-16T13:38:34.601767"
var dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withYear, .withMonth, .withDay, .withTime, .withDashSeparatorInDate, .withColonSeparatorInTime]
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: pulledDate)
```

If you want to know what are the default options, just run this code in a playground:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let options = dateFormatter.formatOptions
options.contains(.withYear)
options.contains(.withMonth)
options.contains(.withWeekOfYear)
options.contains(.withDay)
options.contains(.withTime)
options.contains(.withTimeZone)
options.contains(.withSpaceBetweenDateAndTime)
options.contains(.withDashSeparatorInDate)
options.contains(.withColonSeparatorInTime)
options.contains(.withColonSeparatorInTimeZone)
options.contains(.withFullDate)
options.contains(.withFullTime)
options.contains(.withInternetDateTime)
```

Of course, if your string doesn't contain a timezone, the date formatter will still interpret it in a timezone using its `timeZone` property, which – according to the documentation – defaults to GMT.

Remember to change it before using the formatter if you want to interpret your date in a different timezone:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")
```

Comment: Output is 2017-06-16 13:38:34 +0000 - is there a way to truncate the +0000 using the formatter?

Comment: Use another formatter with the same options plus the `withSpaceBetweenDateAndTime` option.